# Join two database tables in Laravel controller

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have two tables that I want to join in the controller - thought_journal_entries and emotions. A thought journal entry can contain many emotions and the foreign key in the thought_journal_entries table is em_id.

This is an example thought journal entry where the user selected emotions with id 1, 3, 5

[image]

This is the emotions table

[image]

This is the method I'm using to store data within my thought_journal_entries table

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'thought_entry' => 'required'
        ]);

        $entry = new ThoughtJournalEntry;
        $entry->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $entry['entry_date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i');
        $entry->thought = $request->input('thought_entry');
        $entry->em_id = $request->has('emotions') ? $request->get('emotions') : [];
        $entry->tt_id = $request->has('thinking_traps') ? $request->get('thinking_traps') : [];
        $entry->balanced_thought = $request->input('balanced_thought');
        $entry->save();

        return redirect('/dashboard');
    }
```

Comment: You can use eloquent one to many relationship instead of joining tables, see [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Answer (score 1):

In your example `em_id` column it's not a foreign key, it's a string column as I see.
Therefore, you can't execute a `JOIN` query for these tables. In your case, I can recommend create a third table `thought_journal_entry_emotions`.

Here example of code for migration file `2020_02_29_143059_create_thought_journal_entry_emotions_table.php`:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateThoughtJournalEntryEmotionsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('thought_journal_entry_emotions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('thought_journal_entry_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('emotion_id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('thought_journal_entry_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('thought_journal_entries')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('emotion_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('emotions')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('thought_journal_entry_emotions');
    }
}
```

Then you have to add relationships to your models `Emotion` and `ThoughtJournalEntry`.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Emotion extends Model
{
    public function thoughtJournalEntries() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ThoughtJournalEntry::class, 'thought_journal_entry_emotions',
            'emotion_id', 'thought_journal_entry_id');
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ThoughtJournalEntry extends Model
{
    public function emotions() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Emotion::class, 'thought_journal_entry_emotions',
            'thought_journal_entry_id', 'emotion_id');
    }
}
```

After that you can attach `Emotions` to `ThoughtJournalEntry` in your controller using this code:

```
$thoughtJournalEntry = ThoughtJournalEntry::find(1);
$emotion1 = Emotion::find(1);
$emotion2 = Emotion::find(2);
$emotion3 = Emotion::find(3);
$thoughtJournalEntry->emotions()->sync([$emotion1->id, $emotion2->id, $emotion3->id]);
```

And finally you can load your `ThoughtJournalEntry` with `Emotions` in your controller using this code:

```
$thoughtJournalEntry = ThoughtJournalEntry::with('emotions')->find(1);
dd($thoughtJournalEntry);
```

[image]

If you wanna validate and store `Emotions` relations you must update your `store()` method (add new validate rule and `sync()`).
Here example:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'thought_entry' => 'required',
            'emotions' => 'array|max:3',
            'emotions.*' => 'exists:emotions,id'
        ]);

        $entry = new ThoughtJournalEntry;
        $entry->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $entry['entry_date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i');
        $entry->thought = $request->input('thought_entry');
        $entry->tt_id = $request->has('thinking_traps') ? $request->get('thinking_traps') : [];
        $entry->balanced_thought = $request->input('balanced_thought');
        $entry->save();

        $entry->emotions()->sync($request->get('emotions'));

        return redirect('/dashboard');
    }
```

Comment: Hi Oleg, thanks for your answer, going to work on this now. Just one question, I am currently using this to store the selected emotions within the thought_journal_entries table $entry->em_id = $request->has('emotions') ? $request->get('emotions') : [];
How would this change for the new table?

Comment: I have edited my question to include the store() method for my thought_journal_entries table

Comment: Also, I want to validate the form so the user can only select a max of 3 emotions, so could also be 1 selection or 2. Not sure if this changes anything within the controller

Comment: @JoeLeeson , I have edited my answer with updated `store()` method

Answer (score 0):

Joining the table will be a little trickier since the reference value isn't present.
But if you trying to get the names of emotions from using the id stored in the array.
You will need to first save the emotions array in a variable. 
`$em = ["1","3","5"]`

```
$em = ["1","3","5"];
foreach ($em as $e) {
  $emotions = Emotions::find($e * 1); //am using * 1 just make sure its int
  $emotions->em_name;  
}
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

**this should done using [Many to Many Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many), you are using string to store array(thats not mysql way).** *(but looks like you are going to save space in 'thought_journal_entries')*

you can use like this:

```
$journal_entries = thought_journal_entries::find(1);
$icon_ids = json_decode($journal_entries->em_id); // if this column is json
$emocions = emotions::whereIn('id', $icon_ids)->get();
```

but this executing two quarries, that may affect db and server performance